# React-Leaflet 4 with NextJS 14 | Working Setup

Tags: next.js, react-leaflet

I want to display a leaflet map in a NextJS 14 App. Trying to make it work poses these challenges:

- NextJS 14 uses Server Side Rendering (SSR) per default, which is not supported by leaflet
- NextJS 14 uses webpack for bundling, which messes up icons from leaflet

My dependencies are:

```json
"leaflet": "1.9",
"next": "14",
"react": "18",
"react-leaflet": "4",
```

What's the setup for a minimal working configuration?

I searched Stackoverflow and Github for good solutions. I eventually found everything I needed to know, but it took some time to gather all the information.

Thus, I'd like to provide all the necessary information in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Live example**: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/snowy-tdd-5qqjnz)

---

To make this work, we need [leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility?activeTab=readme). The full setup looks like this:

```bash
npx create-next-app@latest
npm install leaflet react-leaflet leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility
npm install -D @types/leaflet
```

Import css and js for `leaflet` and `leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility`. The order is important! Create a map component and make sure to set **width** and **height** on it.

**components/Map.tsx**

```js
"use client";

// START: Preserve spaces to avoid auto-sorting
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.webpack.css";

import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";
// END: Preserve spaces to avoid auto-sorting
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

export default function Map() {
  return (
      <MapContainer
        preferCanvas={true}
        center={[51.505, -0.09]}
        zoom={11}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        style={{ height: "400px", width: "600px" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            This Marker icon is displayed correctly with <i>leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility</i>.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Import the map component:

**app/page.tsx**

```js
"use client";

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const LazyMap = dynamic(() => import("@/components/Map"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
});

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <LazyMap />
    </main>
  );
}
```